# General questions about user management in okta

Tags: okta, okta-api

I just started using okta and I'm a bit lost: I just discovered that in okta you can create groups, and that is very handy since in the application I'm trying to develop I have two types of users, so I would want to create a group for each. However, I didn't understand the okta documentation concerning group creation and group rules. so basically what I would like to do is create two groups and add a rule that would say for instance: if user has this attribute than add him to group 1 but I don't really know how to do that

any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Are you wanting to do this with the Okta API or the Okta GUI admin tool?

Comment: the okta API I think